# C# CodeAnalysis ProtectedAndInternal vs ProtectedOrInternal

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm unclear about the distinction between the `Accessibility` values `ProtectedAndInternal` and `ProtectedOrInternal`.

I found a reference stating `ProtectedOrInternal` maps to the source code construct **protected internal**.

But -- assuming that's correct -- what does it mean for something to be both protected **and** internal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ProtectedOrInternal` corresponds to [`protected internal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected-internal):

> The `protected internal` keyword combination is a member access modifier. A protected internal member is accessible from the current assembly or from types that are derived from the containing class. For a comparison of `protected internal` with the other access modifiers, see [Accessibility Levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels).

`ProtectedAndInternal` corresponds to [`private protected`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private-protected):

> The `private protected` keyword combination is a member access modifier. A private protected member is accessible by types derived from the containing class, but only within its containing assembly. For a comparison of `private protected` with the other access modifiers, see [Accessibility Levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels).

Comment: LOL! I had no idea that functionality was introduced in 7.2. I'll have to find a way to play around with it. Thanx for the references, too.

Answer (score 0):

It's a combination of both types of accesibility levels. Whether some object can be accessed from within the same assembly (internal) or can use the derived types (protected). They are not the same but can be used interchangeably

Comment: Thanx, @Jose, for the feedback